# what event perform in termination action

Tags: java, eclipse

what exactly event perform at the time of termination the program in eclipse?
It means whenever we directly close the program whatever running in eclipse console by pressing red button or close then what exactly event perform ?
 if u know something about this then please share your knowledge with me

Comment: It´s probably a process kill => there is no event in your java code to react to this.

Comment: Do mean an event in Eclipse or an event in your Java program?

Comment: I mean eclipse event suppose u r clicking terminate button then this will calls some method which will terminate or kill our program in console 
so  u have any idea about eclipse event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what is run when you terminate a program run from Eclipse depends on the type of program being run, for most types of launch the code eventually ends up in the `terminate` method of `org.eclipse.debug.core.model.RuntimeProcess`.

RuntimeProcess uses the `destroy` method of `java.lang.Process` to actually kill the program.

Comment: where can we see the eclipse source code @greg-449?

Comment: Install the 'Eclipse SDK' for Kepler the update site is 'http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3'. Once installed check the 'Include all plugins from target in Java search' option on 'Preferences > Plug-in Development'. You should be able to use 'Open Type' to open any source file.